# Find $\frac {1}{\tan3x-\tan x} -\frac {1}{\cot3x-\cot x}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$=\frac{\cot3x-\cot x-\tan3x+\tan x}{\cot3x\tan3x-\tan3x\cot x-\tan xcot3x+\cot x\tan  x}$$

$$=\frac{\cot3x-\cot x-\tan3x+\tan x}{-\tan3x\cot x-\tan x\cot3x}$$
Couldn't simplify after that.

Comment: Do you mean $\tan(3x)$ or $\tan^3(x)$?

Comment: Tan 3x not tan^3x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\tan3x=a,\tan x=b$

$$\frac{1}{\tan3x-\tan{x}}-\frac{1}{\cot3x-\cot{x}}  =\dfrac1{a-b}--\frac{1}{\dfrac1a-\dfrac1b}=\dfrac{1+ab}{a-b}$$

Now $\tan(A-B)=\dfrac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\tan3x-\tan{x}}-\frac{1}{\cot3x-\cot{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin3x}{\cos3x}-\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}-\frac{1}{\frac{\cos3x}{\sin3x}-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos3x\cos x}{\sin3x\cos{x}-\cos3x\sin{x}}+\frac{\sin3x\sin{x}}{\sin3x\cos{x}-\cos3x\sin{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\cos3x\cos x}{\sin2x}+\frac{\sin3x\sin{x}}{\sin2x}=\cot2x$$

Comment: Can you show some more steps so that I can understand it well?

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: @user466377 You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Write $$\tan( 3x)=\frac{1}{\cot(3x)}$$ and $$\tan(x)=\frac{1}{\cot(x)}$$

Then equation transforms into $$\frac{\cot(3x)\cot(x)+1}{\cot(3x)-\cot(x)}$$ which is simply $$\cot(3x-x)=\cot(2x)$$